# brain.js problem with importing LSTM network from json

Tags: brain.js

I've made a brain.js LSTM network, predicting addition. Then I saved it to a .json file using `net.toJSON()`
However, it doesn't seem to work.  The `traindata.json` was successfully created, no errors. However, I get an error:

```
/home/runner/AngryBlaringTelevision/node_modules/brain.js/dist/brain.js:18102
      var matrix = new Matrix(json.rows, json.columns);
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined
    at Function.fromJSON (/home/runner/AngryBlaringTelevision/node_modules/brain.js/dist/brain.js:18102:36)
    at LSTM.fromJSON (/home/runner/AngryBlaringTelevision/node_modules/brain.js/dist/brain.js:20142:26)
    at /home/runner/AngryBlaringTelevision/index.js:9:7
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
```

My code:

```
const brain = require('brain.js');
const fs = require('fs');

const LSTM = brain.recurrent.LSTM;
const net = new LSTM();

fs.readFile('traindata.json', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  net.fromJSON(data);
  console.log("file loaded");
});
```

Also, here's the link to my `traindata.json` file on pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/tBZyxq1R
I don't have an idea how to solve this error. It seems like it's an error with brain.js.

I have also tried `net.run()` after importing the file, but it also didn't work.

Comment: After looking at your training data, it looks like rows/columns are properties in an object called 'input'. Is it possible that you need to pass json.input.rows instead of just json.rows?

Comment: I see what you mean... However it's a problem with brain.js I think so I will make an issue on brain.js's github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what might be going on is that what you're passing into BrainJS is not actually JSON.

In your code, you have this:

```
fs.readFile('traindata.json', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  net.fromJSON(data);
  console.log("file loaded");
});
```

When I tried running your code, I saw the same error you saw.
Using `JSON.parse()` seemed to fix the issue.

In other words, when I changed `net.fromJSON(data);` to `net.fromJSON(JSON.parse(data));`, the error disappeared.

Comment: Agreed. `JSON.parse()` is the way to go